# Is there a way to get xquery for...in loop to evaluate an xquery dynamically created as a string by another function?

Tags: xquery

I have an xquery function that dynamically builds an xquery as a string using concat() and returns the string.  The query output will return a series of rows when executed. I want to be able to execute this function's output as the input of a for..in loop that will go through the rows and produce the final output.  I cannot figure out how to get the for..in loop to execute the string output of the first query. I'm using xbase, an would like a universal solution if possible.

I have tried to find an evaluate or execute function to execute the string, something similar to SQL's exec() command, and have only found xhive:evaluate().  I cannot find the code (it may be proprietary) for it or the library referenced by 'xhive:', so I cannot import it.

The first query looks like this:

```
declare function ps:searchQuery() as xs:string
{
if ($aliasin) then  
   concat (
      'for $app in /CE/APP/ROW ',
      'for $e in /CE/ENTITY/ROW[id = $app/entity] ',
      iau:where( iau:textEq( '$app/alias',$aliasin)),
     ' return <row> { $app/entity } { $e/name } { $app/alias } { $app/backup_alias } { $app/approval_order } {$app/buyer} </row> ') 
        else ()
};
```

I want to use it like this:

```
    let $rows :=  
     for $urow in somenamespace:evaluate(ps:searchQuery())    
         let ...
    return
        <row id="{string($AliasName)}"> ...
        </row>
```

is there a way to universally evaluate like this?

The final output would be the rows returned by the searchQuery() properly formatted and renamed, which is no problem. but getting the string to execute is.

Comment: Do you use BaseX? See http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module#xquery:eval.

Comment: For eXist, see http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#eval.1

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard function for this, but many XQuery processors have some kind of extension that will do it. In Saxon, for example, you can use `saxon:compile-query()` to prepare a query and `saxon:query()` to execute it.